# Probablity of getting white balls. (Explanation).

Tags: probability

Question : 
There are 8 white and 4 black balls in an urn. 4 balls are to be drawn. Find probability that 1st and 3rd are white given that exactly 3 are white. 
(With and Without replacement).

Answer:

With replacement :

Selecting 3 whites = ${(\frac{8}{12})^3 * \frac{4}{12} * 4}$

Sample Space = {WWWB, WBWW}

P that first and third are white = ${(\frac{8}{12})^3 * \frac{4}{12} * 2}$

Probability that first and third are white given that 3 are white = ${(\frac{8}{12})^3 * \frac{4}{12} * 2}$ $\div$  ${(\frac{8}{12})^3 * \frac{4}{12} * 4}$ =  0.5

Without replacement :

Selecting 3 whites = ${8 \choose 3} * {4 \choose 1}$

Total selections = ${12 \choose 4}$

P that 3 are white = $\frac{{8 \choose 3} {4 \choose 1}}{12 \choose 4}$

Sample Space = {WWWB, WBWW}

P that 1 and 3 are white = $\frac 8{12} \frac 7{11} \frac 6 {10} \frac 4 {9} * 2$

But answer for replacement is wrong according to solution.

[image: Answer according to book]

Comment: Clear evidence of post-senile immaturity: My mind immediately wondered what the probability is of getting blue balls. Oy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed answer is wrong.

In both cases the probability $p(A|B)=0.5$, where $A=$ the 1st and 3rd are W, and $B=$ 3W,1B were drawn.

In both cases the possibilities for $B$ are WWWB,WWBW,WBWW and BWWW, and the possibilities for $A$ and $B$ are WWWB and WBWW.

In the with-replacement case each of these four has prob $\frac{8^34}{12^4}$. In the without-replacement case each has prob $\frac{8\times7\times6\times4}{12\times11\times10\times9}$, so in both cases $p(A|B)=2/4$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for without replacement has a glaring error.

$\require{cancel}\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{\mathsf P(F\cap E) = \dfrac{2}{\dbinom{12}{4}}}}} \begin{array}{l} \longleftarrow\text{counts the permutations of 3 identical white and 1 black ball} \\ \longleftarrow\text{counts the selections of any 4 balls from 12 distinct balls} \end{array}$

The numerator *must* count the same *sort* of thing as the denominator; so it should be done thus:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(F\cap E) & = \dfrac{\dbinom{8}{2}\,2!\;\dbinom{6}{1}\,\dbinom{4}{1}\,2!} {\dbinom{12}{4}\;4!} & \begin{array}{l}\longleftarrow\begin{cases}\text{select 2 of 8 distinct white balls for special places}\\ \text{arrange the balls in first and third place,}\\ \text{select 1 of 6 remaining white balls, 1 of 4 black}\\\text{arrange the balls in second and fourth place}\end{cases}\\[1ex]\longleftarrow\text{select 4 of 12 distinct balls, and arrange them}\end{array}
\\[2ex] & = \dfrac{112}{495}
\\[3ex]
\therefore \mathsf P(F\mid E) & = \frac 1 2
\end{align}$